# Trying to build deploy my Vite react app on render and getting this error. I figured it has something to do with the Yup module but it is installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, production, yup

[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "Yup" from "/opt/render/project/src/src/pages/Login.jsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to  `build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "Yup" from "/opt/render/project/src/src/pages/Login.jsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM  If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to  `build.rollupOptions.external`
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at viteWarn (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:48205:27)
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at onwarn (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react/dist/index.mjs:247:9)
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at onRollupWarning (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:48234:9)
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at onwarn (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:47965:13)
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24276:13
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at Object.logger [as onLog] (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25950:9)
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24862:26)
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at file:///opt/render/project/src/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24822:26
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM  npm ERR! errno 1
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM  npm ERR! dunis-ui@0.0.0 build: `vite build`
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 1
Nov 6 02:44:13 PM  npm ERR!

I tried building the app locally and it worked. I was even able to preview it on my localhost using "Vite preview" but it keeps failing to build when being deployed on render

Comment: Please improve your question. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).